# Kaleido vm in read-only mode

Tags: ethereum, kaleido

I've successfully deployed the following contract on Kaleido:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Greeter {
    string public greeting;

    function Greeter() {
        greeting = 'Hello';
    }

    function setGreeting(string _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() constant returns (string) {
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

I try to interact with the contract like so:

```
from web3 import Web3
from web3.providers import HTTPProvider
from solc import compile_source
from web3.contract import ConciseContract

# Solidity source code
contract_source_code = '''
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Greeter {
    string public greeting;

    function Greeter() {
        greeting = 'Hello';
    }

    function setGreeting(string _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() constant returns (string) {
        return greeting;
    }
}
'''

compiled_sol = compile_source(contract_source_code) 
contract_interface = compiled_sol[':Greeter']

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("https://user:password@u0telyzine-u0od4ny83j-rpc.us-east-2.kaleido.io"))

# address from previous deployment
contract_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress("0x4c94e89d5ec3125339906109f143673f40868df2")

greeter = w3.eth.contract(
    address=contract_address,
    abi=contract_interface['abi'],
)

print('Default contract greeting: {}'.format(
    greeter.functions.greet().call()
))

# --- this hangs ---
print('Setting the greeting to Nihao...')
tx_hash = greeter.functions.setGreeting('Nihao').transact({ 'from': w3.eth.accounts[0], 'gas': 100000})

w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)

print('Updated contract greeting: {}'.format(
    greeter.functions.greet().call()
))

reader = ConciseContract(greeter)
assert reader.greet() == "Nihao"
```

However, when I try to submit a transaction which calls `setGreeting` the transaction hangs. Viewing the Kaleido logs, I see `VM in read-only mode. Mutating opcode prohibited`. Also, when I visit the block explorer for my node, the transactions don't load while the blocks do.

[image: transactions not loading]

What can I do about this read only mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

moghadasian

I could not recreate your "VM in read-only mode" when submitting a transaction - that worked successfully.
However, I had to do a bit of investigation to get web3/python connecting to Kaleido - so I'm adding a separate answer to help others trying to get going.

### Configuring HTTPS authentication to Kaleido from Python web3

On my Mac, with a default pip3 installation of web3, I found the only way to configure the Python Session with auth was to use a `$HOME/.netrc` file such as:

```
machine u0oaXXXXXX-u0c4XXXXXX-rpc.us-east-2.kaleido.io
login u0d0bxXXXX
password jA-pJdIrcRaIx7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

### Configure web3 for Geth/PoA

My chain was using Geth/PoA, so I had to follow the instructions here, to install the required middleware:
http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/middleware.html#geth-style-proof-of-authority

### Updated example including deployment of contract

Here is the python3 that successfully deployed and reported `Updated contract greeting: Nihao`.
You will need to change your `HTTPProvider` to the HTTPS RPC URL of your node, but without the authentication headers.

```
from web3 import Web3
from web3.providers import HTTPProvider
from solc import compile_source
from web3.contract import ConciseContract
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

# Solidity source code
contract_source_code = '''
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Greeter {
    string public greeting;

    function Greeter() {
        greeting = 'Hello';
    }

    function setGreeting(string _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() constant returns (string) {
        return greeting;
    }
}
'''

compiled_sol = compile_source(contract_source_code) 
contract_interface = compiled_sol['<stdin>:Greeter']

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("https://u0oaXXXXXX-u0c4XXXXXX-rpc.us-east-2.kaleido.io"))
w3.middleware_stack.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

Greeter = w3.eth.contract(abi=contract_interface['abi'], bytecode=contract_interface['bin'])
tx_hash = Greeter.constructor().transact({ 'from': w3.eth.accounts[0], 'gas': 1000000})
tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
print('Deployed greeter contract: {}'.format(tx_receipt.contractAddress))

# address from previous deployment
contract_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress(tx_receipt.contractAddress)

greeter = w3.eth.contract(
    address=contract_address,
    abi=contract_interface['abi'],
)

print('Default contract greeting: {}'.format(
    greeter.functions.greet().call()
))

print('Setting the greeting to Nihao...')
tx_hash = greeter.functions.setGreeting('Nihao').transact({ 'from': w3.eth.accounts[0], 'gas': 100000})

w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)

print('Updated contract greeting: {}'.format(
    greeter.functions.greet().call()
))

reader = ConciseContract(greeter)
assert reader.greet() == "Nihao"
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help Peter. I'm not sure what was going on, maybe the problem came about because of Quorum + RAFT. I've since switched to Geth + PoA and it's working flawlessly now except for the fact that contract deployment takes more time than before (a few seconds instead of instant).

Answer (score 1):

moghadasian,

The "VM in read-only mode" is because you are using `call` to interact with your Smart Contract method. So it's just calling your method in a read-only mode. You would use this to call methods on contracts that query data - without having to submit a transaction to the chain.

[edit] - the above advice is generally helpful for "VM in read-only mode", but if you're trying out python web3, you pobably want the other answer with a full working example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51155413/4972840 [/edit]

Regards, Peter

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I understand. The call function `greeter.functions.greet().call()` works fine. It's the other function, `greeter.functions.setGreeting('Nihao').transact({ 'from': w3.eth.accounts[0], 'gas': 100000})` which hangs because of what looks like a read-only vm.

Comment: Hi Paymahn,
I tried your solidity on Mac with the Python web3 py-solc installed via pip3.
After exploring the web3 code, I found that to set the HTTPS authentication for Kaleido, I could set a `.netrc` file such as:
```
machine rcNs@u0oaulux2d-u0c4XXXXXX-rpc.us-east-2.kaleido.io 
login u0d0bxXXXX
password jA-pJdIrcRaIx7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: I was then connected and received:  web3.exceptions.ValidationError: The field extraData is 97 bytes, but should be 32. It is quite likely that you are connected to a POA chain. Refer http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/middleware.html#geth-style-proof-of-authority for more details. The full extraData is: HexBytes(' ...

Continuing to work through it

Comment: ... will move to an answer once I have worked through getting web3/python to connect